# Binding using datacontext

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

What do I set datacontext to if I want to bind properties from a class:

```
<Rectangle DataContext="Scaling" Height="{Binding VerticalSliderHeight}" Width="{Binding VerticalSliderHeight}">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/fader.png"/>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

The class:

```
public static class Scaling
{
    //Just For Slider Resource
    public static float VerticalSliderHeight { get; set; }
    public static float VerticalSliderWidth { get; set; }
    //
}
```

answers suggested are for WPF

more info on the xaml side:

```
<Page.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyleVertical">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">

                                            <Rectangle Height="60" Width="30">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/fader.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                            </Rectangle>

                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyleHorizontal">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">

                                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalThumbRect" Height="30" Width="60">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/fader2.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                            </Rectangle>

                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                  x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                  Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                  Margin="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeMargin}"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                  FontWeight="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                  TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <Grid x:Name="SliderContainer" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="1" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                            <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" MinHeight="44">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
                  Fill="DimGray"
                  Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                  <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Fill="DimGray" Grid.Row="1" />
                  <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
              Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}"
              Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyleHorizontal}"
              DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.RowSpan="3"
              Grid.Column="1"
              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" MinWidth="44" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect"
                  Fill="DimGray"
                  Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                  Fill="DimGray"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="2" />

                                <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb"
              Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}"
              Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyleVertical}"
              DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

SO it seems that the bindings are having trouble within the page resources. Any ideas?

Comment: this is uwp not WPF

Comment: You want to set the *DataContext* to a static class or any class? It must be in XAML or can be in code? Generally you can do it from code - set it directly, do it via binding or via resource.

Comment: little bit off topic but why are you using the old bindings? they are kind of replaced by x:Bind. this are compiled bindings. They are faster and consume less memory, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

Comment: x:bind cant be used in styles

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it might be a little Overwhelming if you're new to the `DataBinding` and `MVVM` concepts so try to wrap your head around it with an open mind. I'll try to make it as straight forward as I can.

---

There are two ways you can go about it,

1. Bind the View  to the codeBehind
2. Or Bind the View  to a simple ViewModel (MVVM Pattern)

I'll provide answers for both, Just the initial part is different and then they all have a common functionality.

**For Binding the View to the CodeBehind**

For this you need to bind the view to it's own codeBehind to let the view know that the binding you're using are in the CodeBehind to do this, On your `<Page>` tag use

`DataContext = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Now you've got your `View(.xaml)` to listen to your `codeBehind(.xaml.cs)`

**Binding it to a ViewModel (.cs)**

For this create a new `Class` under your project and name it `"ViewNameViewModel"`. Now go to your View and then add the `NameSpace`in the `<Page>` tag using `xmlns:ViewModels="yourNameSpace"` please note Visual Studio would show you intellisense so you can simply just pick from there. Also the Local namespace is already added so if you have a viewModel in the Local nameSpace (i.e no sub-Directory) then you can skip adding the NameSpace.

Now that you've added the NameSpace, you need to set the `DataContext` of the View, do it by adding the below code under the `<Page>` tag

```
<Page xmlns:ViewModels="using:MyTestApp.ViewModels">
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainPageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Now that you've got your View's `DataContext` binded in both cases, the Common part:

---

Refactor your `class` to use `double` properties as `Height` and `Width` are `double` and don't make them `static` also make them raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` with the use of the `INotifyPropertyChanged`interface

```
public class Scaling :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public double VerticalSliderHeight
    {
        get { return verticalSliderHeight; }
        set 
        { 
           verticalSliderHeight = value;       
           NotifyPropertyChanged("VerticalSliderHeight"); 
        }
    }

    private double verticalSliderWidth;
    public double VerticalSliderWidth
    {
        get { return verticalSliderWidth; }
        set 
        { 
           verticalSliderWidth = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("VerticalSliderWidth"); 
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

This ways as soon as the values in the property changes, the view updates itself to the latest values.

In your `.cs` (CodeBehind or ViewModel) add a property, Also make your `.cs` implement `NotifyPropertyChanged` and the property as :

```
    private Scaling mySliderData;
    public Scaling MySliderData
    {
        get { return mySliderData; }
        set 
        {
            mySliderData = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MySliderData"); 
        }
    }
```

Now it's all done, Simply bind your element, like below:

```
    <Rectangle Height="{Binding MySliderData.VerticalSliderHeight}" Width="{Binding MySliderData.VerticalSliderHeight}">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/fader.png"/>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

This ways your code is scalable and easy to refactor. I hope I solved your query if there's anything I'll be happy to help in the comments section

Comment: I'm still getting this error:Error: BindingExpression path error: 'VerticalSliderWidth' property not found on 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<Double>'. BindingExpression: Path='VerticalSliderWidth' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<Double>'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle' (Name='null'); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Comment: <Page DataContext = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

Comment: I should mention this rectangle is inside Page.Resources

Comment: So is the rectangle a part of a DataTemplate? Could you please share some sample project or more of your code. It's tough to see what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Here is a more update post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812518/how-to-access-the-rectangles-width-height-via-c-sharp-code